# Limit disk space consumption of Redshift queries

Tags: redshift

How can I limit the **disk space** used by queries in Redshift to prevent the cluster from running out of disk space?

Simple queries on a large table can take up a huge amount of space.
I ran out of disk space with a simple single test query with a limit 1 condition on a large table 80GB of a total of 160GB, which made the database unusable until I restarted it manually.
Vacuuming the table brought the table size down to 1G, but the same query still consumes up to 10G.

This means the solution is not fit for production since I expect multiple parallel queries and I don't see any way to handle the scenario gracefully. I mean I would fine if the query just got killed, but that it just completely locks down the database is horrible both security and usability wise.

I found https://aws.amazon.com/de/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redshift-wlm-memory-allocation/ which if I understand it correctly means that it is possible to control memory usage of queries, but I didn't find a good way to do the same for disk space consumption.

Comment: Might help to provide the query you used as an example. I'm not a Redshift expert, but on general principle, non-DML type of queries, e.g. straight `SELECT`, shouldn't really use any disk space (unless there's an unusual event like it ran out of Memory to process a specific kind of operation, and needed to spill to disk). Also, FWIW, if Redshift functions like other database systems, `LIMIT 1` might just be executed towards the end of the workflow, after it's already loaded all of the data off disk first. Better to filter by a predicate (e.g. `WHERE` clause) instead, to get earlier filtering.

Comment: I have found the possibility to configure the `query_temp_blocks_to_disk` in the workload management so I will give it a shot and report back https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/cm-c-wlm-query-monitoring-rules.html#cm-c-wlm-defining-query-monitoring-rules